# jQuery click event listener inside keyup event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a `keyup` event listener that dynamically creates and adds a new button to the page. Then that button needs another `click` event listener that depends on data only available inside the `keyup` listener to do its job.

This is the code I have:

```
$('.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.prev().text() != 'Uhr') {
        return;
    }

    if ($('.select2-no-results').is(':visible')) {
        if (!$('#insertWatch').length) {
            $($('<a href="javascript:;" id="insertWatch" class="btn btn-xs red" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px;">Uhr Einfügen</a>')).insertAfter(this);
        }
    } else {
        $('#insertWatch').remove();
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#insertWatch', function(e) {
        alert('Added')
        $.post('/insert/watch', { name: self.val() }, function(response) {
            $('#supplier_id').prepend($('<option value="' + response + '" selected>' + self.val() + '</option>'));
            $('.select2-drop-mask, .select2-drop-active').css('display', 'none');
        });

        return false;
    });

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The `click` event listener does not fire at all when the added button is clicked. I'm unable to figure out why. So to sum this up, `alert('Added')` never pops up.

Comment: I [can't reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/owztrwrq/). Is it possible for you to recreate the problem with a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Well this is really strange because it wont work on my platform!

Comment: Hi Aborted, if you use `<a href=javascript:void(0)>link</a>` You don't need to `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching the even when the element is created.

Something like:

```
$('.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.prev().text() != 'Uhr') {
        return;
    }

    if ($('.select2-no-results').is(':visible')) {
        if (!$('#insertWatch').length) {
            $($('<a href="javascript:;" id="insertWatch" class="btn btn-xs red" style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px;">Uhr Einfügen</a>')).insertAfter(this).on('click', '#insertWatch', function(e) {
        alert('Added')
        $.post('/insert/watch', { name: self.val() }, function(response) {
            $('#supplier_id').prepend($('<option value="' + response + '" selected>' + self.val() + '</option>'));
            $('.select2-drop-mask, .select2-drop-active').css('display', 'none');
        });

        return false;
    });;
        }
    } else {
        $('#insertWatch').remove();
    }



    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your solution solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/cp34ybca/

```
$('.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var button = "<button class='myButton'>my button</button>";

    if ($(this).val() != 'Uhr' && !$('.myButton').length) {
       $('body').append(button);
           $('.myButton').on('click', function(){
           $('i').html('Clicked!');
       });
    }else  if ($(this).val() === 'Uhr'){
        $('.myButton').remove();
        $('i').html('');
    }
});
```